# Questions on Theon's Ladder

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Imagine we want to use Theon's ladder to approximate $\sqrt{3}$. The appropriate expressions are
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+y_{n-1}$$

$$y_n=x_n+2x_{n-1}$$

Rungs 6 through 10 in the approximation of $\sqrt{3}$ are

$\{\{208, 120\},\{568, 328\}, \{1552, 896\}, \{4240, 2448\}, \{11584, 6688\}\}$

a) Compute the two values in rung 11 of the ladder.

I'm assuming that all I need to do plug into the formula. So:

$x_{11}=x_{10}+y_{10}$

$x_{11}=6688+11584=18272$

$y_{11}=x_{11}+2x_{10}$

$y_{11}=18272+2(6688)=31648$

Is this correct?Part b is really what I am struggling with.

b) The figure below shows five rectangles whose dimensions correspond to rungs 6 through 10 above. That is, the lower left corner of each is at (0,0), while the upper right corners are at $(208,120),(568, 328),...,(11584,6688)$ Are any of these rectangles similar to each other? Explain, briefly, your reasoning.

All I can think is that 6688 and 120 have a gcd of 8, and the gcd of 11584 and 208 is 16. Not really sure how to articulate that this helps with the similarity of the rectangles. Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: [Please do not delete and re-ask questions!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247190/using-theons-ladder-questions)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that, if you can show that the ratios of the rectangles are getting closer to $\sqrt 3$, then none of them should be similar to each other. So you need to have some way to track $\frac{y_n}{x_n}$ in each iteration.

If you try some related expressions, you might discover that tracking $y_n^2 - 3x_n^2$ actually helps you a bit. Playing with the iteration relations you will get:

$$
y_n^2 - 3x_n^2 = -2(y_{n-1}^2 - 3x_{n-1}^2).
$$

From this, 
$$
\left|\left(\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)^2-3\right| = 2\left(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}\right)^2\left|\left(\frac{y_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}}\right)^2-3\right|.
$$

This leads to our assertion. Can you finish up the arguments?

Comment: why is it that when the ratio of the rectangles are getting closer to $\sqrt 3$ that they should not be similar? also do you mean ratio of areas, sides?

Comment: Two rectangles are similar if and only if the ratios (i.e. length/width) are the same. If the ratio gets strictly closer to $\sqrt 3$ then none of the ratios should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Calling $\lambda_n = \frac{y_n}{x_n}$ we have

$$
\lambda_n = \frac{\lambda_{n-1}+3}{\lambda_{n-1}+1}
$$

giving a sequence $\lambda_n$ with limit at

$$
\lambda = \frac{\lambda+3}{\lambda+1}\Rightarrow \lambda^2 = 3
$$